# javascript if value is number to number

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, numbers

Is there any way to check if value is in a number range? Like my example:

```
if (battery.level == 70 to 100) {
  $('#battery').css('background-image', 'url("battery_full.png")');
}
```

What's the syntax for that? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (battery.level >= 70 && battery.level <= 100) {
```

Comment: With a note that `'70%'` is not a number, and can't be used here; you need to transform it to a number first, using `parseFloat('70%')`.

Comment: Thanks Amadan, that's true. But I think `Like my example:` they are using Jquery, most probably that battery.level is already a numeric property and they put up that condition just to explain. I'm almost sure jQuery wont be storing that property in a string format. This answer is based on that assumption

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
if ( value >= 70 && value <= 100)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this :

```
function inRange(n, from, to) {
    return n >= from && n <= to;
}

if (inRange(battery.levelPercent, 70, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

**YOU CAN CHECK NUMBER LIKE**

```
if ( battery.level >= 70 && battery.level <= 100)
{
}
```

**NOT A STRING**  **LIKE**  `('70%' to '100%')`

Answer (score 0):

You better remove `%` from `battery.level` to compare it with `number`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y3Cc2/)**

```
level = battery.level.replace('%', '');    
if (level >= 70 && level <= 100) {
  $('#battery').css('background-image', 'url("battery_full.png")');
}
```

You can also use `parseFloat` or `parseInt`

```
level = parseFloat(battery.level);    
if (level >= 70 && level <= 100) {
  $('#battery').css('background-image', 'url("battery_full.png")');
}
```

Comment: Why not `parseInt` or `parseFloat`? Well... :D

Comment: @Amadan a plus(+) sign make it integer.

Answer (score 0):

`70%` is actually not a number. However, you could get rid of the invalidating `%` by naming your variable `battery.levelPercent` instead and adding the percent sign whenever it needs to be output.

Then, you could check the number like this:

```
if (typeof battery.levelPercent === "number") {
    if (battery.levelPercent >= 70 && battery.levelPercent <= 100) {
        $('#battery').css('background-image', 'url("battery_full.png")');

    } // else, not in range

} // else, not a number
```